# src/tests/soname.h:1:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found #include "openssl/opensslv.h"

Tags: r, openssl, macos-big-sur, libssl

I am trying to install some R packages (devtools and tidyverse) but when I run the command:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

I get several errors, the first of which states:

> src/tests/soname.h:1:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
> #include "openssl/opensslv.h"

I have installed via Conda the packages openssl and libssl, but nothing seems to work.
I have macOS BigSur and R version 4.0.3 installed.
I have also looked up the web, but as aforementioned I could not solve such riddle!

Giuseppe

Comment: Is it possible that you might only need to install `openssl` with `brew`?

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly, although I had also to install another library: `libgit2` as follows: `brew install libgit2`